# SFTP - check free space available

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using [Renci SSH.NET](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/) library for secure ftp connection. Now I have to check free disk space available on remote SFTP server. How can I do this?

Comment: @leemo SFTP is not FTP and has nothing in common with it. SFTP version 6 lets one check available space on the volume.

Comment: OpenSSH SFTP server supports the `statvfs@openssh.com` extension that returns that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eugene commented, SFTP protocol actually have an API to check available space (`SSH_FXP_EXTENDED` request name `space-available` defined in [draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00)).

But Renci SSH.NET library does not support the extension. Also worth noting that most SSH/SFTP servers (notably OpenSSH, as the one the most widespread) do not support this extension either. So client-side support won't help much here.

As Salva has commented, OpenSSH on the other hand supports `statvfs@openssh.com` proprietary extension with very similar functionality as `space-available`. And Renci SSH.NET library supports that too (via `SftpClient.GetStatus`). So if you are sure that you work against OpenSSH server, you can use that.