# how to find disk space in sftp

Tags: c#, sftp

I'm newcomer to SFTP. i have created one location as SFTP server in my machine ( windows 7). I am able to upload the files through my project. i'm using renci.Sshnet dll. Now i'm trying to get remaining disk space in SFTP server. I'm trying to get space by execute a command. But i'm stuck with that and getting following error

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the    number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
Source=Renci.SshNet
StackTrace:
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
   at Renci.SshNet.Channels.Channel.WaitHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
   at Renci.SshNet.Channels.ChannelSession.SendExecRequest(String command)
   at Renci.SshNet.SshCommand.BeginExecute(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at LogFileArchive.LogFileArchive.runningcommand() in C:\Utilities\LogFileArchive\Program.cs:line 381
   at LogFileArchive.LogFileArchive.Main(String[] args) in C:\Utilities\LogFileArchive\Program.cs:line 475
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

The source code which i have tried is as follows

```
using (SshClient sshclient = new SshClient("Host", "Port", "Username", "Password"))
{
    sshclient.Connect();
    var cmd1 = sshclient.RunCommand("echo 1");
    Console.WriteLine(cmd1.Result);

    var cmd2 = sshclient.RunCommand("echo 2");
    Console.WriteLine(cmd2.Result);

    sshclient.Disconnect();
}
```

Please advise is it right approach? or give any other solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769776/sftp-check-free-space-available refer this @Manikandan

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Boopathi. Already I have seen this link. But i want to know any other samples to get these details.

Comment: "other samples": In what sense other?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl sorry for that. can you let me know is any other way to get remaining disk space on SFTP using c#.

Comment: Also, you mention SFTP in question title and tags, yet you do not use SFTP at all in your code.

Comment: Next, from your code/question/callstack it's not clear what call does throw the exception. There's no mention of `SshClient` in the callstack.

Comment: I'm using Renci.SshNet.dll. for connecting to the SFTP ( secure FTP) server. I am able to transfer file using sftpclient included in the same dll. But whenever i tried to run a command using sshclient.RunCommand() i'm getting the error. In the above code i'm getting error at sshclient.RunCommand("echo 1");

Comment: Your code works just fine for me when used against OpenSSH server. What server are you connecting to? Have you checked a Renci log? Did you try to debug the exception?

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl. I have to connect windows server 2003. At the moment i'm trying to connect to my local machine which is windows 7 as SFTP server and i have installed both Core FTP Server and Client (Core FTP Lite).

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the title question**:
As mentioned in [SFTP - check free space available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19769776/850848), there is only one official way to query a disk space with the SFTP. And it won't work with the SSH.NET client library (not sure about Core FTP server). Then there's a proprietary OpenSSH extension that won't work with Core FTP Server.

**Regarding the exception**:
You should really start by debugging the exception, as this is clearly kind of a bug in the SSH.NET library, so it's difficult to help you remotely. The library is open source with no dependencies, so building and debugging it is pretty easy. On the other hand, it's quite likely that the exception is caused by some error returned from the Core FTP Server (as your code works ok, when run against OpenSSH). So another approach is to find out why (if) Core FTP Server errors.

As it is Windows server, you should try using some other command than the `echo`. Note that the `echo` is not executable on Windows, it's an internal command of Windows command-line interpreter. So it's quite common that it cannot be used as a command directly (the same way you cannot run the `echo` from *Start > Run*). Alternatively try to run the `echo` indirectly using the `cmd.exe /c "echo 1"`.

Also did you check server's log file?

Next, it's worth first trying to run the command in GUI SSH client to see what the output is. E.g. in PuTTY go to *Connection > SSH* and specify your command in *Remote command* (this is equivalent to `SshClient.RunCommand`). On the first *Session* page better select *Never* for *Close window on exit* to make sure you can see the output.